# Why MySQL5.7 seems to ignore subquery

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have the following SQL query which behaves as I expect in MySQL 8, but does not produce the same a nd correct results in version 5.7 and I can't figure out why...

```
SELECT concat(table_name, '_', column_name) as missing
    from information_schema.columns
    where table_schema = 'ref_schema' and table_name in ('aliases','indiv') and
            concat(table_name, '_', column_name) not in (
                select concat( columns.table_name,'_',columns.column_name) as v
                from information_schema.columns   
                where table_schema = 'new_schema' 
    );
```

The query is basically comparing 2 table (aliases and indiv) structures from 2 schemas (ref_schema and new_schema) and is supposed to list columns which are missing in the second one...

Assuming that the table structures are identical in both schema, it should return 0 row. Which it does with MySQL8. But in version 5.7, it returns the full set of columns. It seems that the "NOT IN" condition is not properly executed.

I am using MySQL8 for debugging purposes. 5.7 is for prod. So I need to have it running on 5.7.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are not picking from 'aliases','indiv' in the sub query so if could find columns from other tables in new_schema. BTW if the data is the same then the result will be the same irrespective of version.

Comment: Do not use a char legal for to use in an object name as a separator - this may give excess matchings. You may use simple `WHERE (a,b) NOT IN (select a,b FROM ...)`. And do not use WHERE IN at all - join 2 table copies.

Comment: *in version 5.7, it returns the full set of columns* Execute both SELECTs without NOT IN and compare outputs - there is regilar difference somewhere.

Comment: Thx Akina for your first comment. Indeed, applying your recommendation, helped me to find that CONCAT() NOT IN SELECT CONCAT() was responsible for the bug I had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying Akina fix gives the correct answer and fixed my issue:

```
SELECT concat(table_name, '_', column_name) as missing
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE
    table_schema = 'ref_schema' and
    table_name in ('aliases','indiv') and
    (table_name,column_name) not in (
        select table_name,column_name
        from information_schema.columns   
        where table_schema = 'new_schema' 
    );
```

Now both platform provides the same and exact result. Syntax is even easier to read!